# Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:64462/g8aDzix3Bmw=/ws

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-emulator, flutter-web

Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:64462/g8aDzix3Bmw=/ws
how can i solve this

[image]

Comment: There is no detailed explanation of what are you trying to solve. Do you have issues with flutter showing just a white screen?

Comment: Try running with `flutter run --verbose` to get the more detailed error and add it here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.